# Get the top most searched terms from search-records, ignoring any duplicate entry for a search-term by any user within a given timeframe(Hrs)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

We are currently pulling the top 5 searches from the below entity ordered by search count for searches conducted in last N days(refer effectiveSearchDate in below query).

```
SELECT *, count(t.searchterms)
FROM searchRecords t
WHERE t.SearchDate >= effectiveSearchDate   
GROUP BY t.searchTerms  
ORDER BY count(t.searchTerms) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

**Where,** `effectiveSearchDate` is the date from which you want top-search results till date, say `'2019-04-01 00:00:00'` for top search results since last 5 days.

Refer Image below.
[image]

Now, in order to avoid search spamming (any user continuously searching a particular term multiple times just to bring it up in top searches), we introduced a `userId` column to this existing entity and want to update the query which will ignore any such spams searches by a user for a particular searchterm within a designated period(say 2Hrs).

For eg: let's analyze further on the most searched term above -'voting day':

SELECT * FROM SearchRecords
 where SearchTerms like "voting day";

[image]

Here, If you notice its only these 3 users who have searched this keyword multiple times. Hence, we would like to discard multiple searches done by a user within a designated period of n-Hrs(say- 2hrs), i.e. count all searches by a user for any particular term within a span of 2hrs as one(1).Thus, the final count of this search word - **"voting day"** should be **3** instead of **12** and similarly for all the search counts.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write the logical approch first -

add a new column 'valid_search_flag' using ROW_NUMBER() and logic should be

Partition By -

- userid
- searchterm
- Date part of searchdate ('yyyy-MM-dd')
- Hour part of searchdate('HH') devided by 3 (3 is defining here time frame 3 hours)

Order By -

- searchdate

Logic to generate **valid_search_flag** would be:

> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid,searchterm, FORMAT(searchdate,
>   'yyyy-MM-dd'), FORMAT(searchdate, 'hh')/3 ORDER BY searchdate) AS
>   **valid_search_flag**

Now using filter "valid_search_flag = 1" all the duplicate search can be filtered:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid,searchterm, FORMAT(searchdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), FORMAT(searchdate, 'hh')/3 ORDER BY searchdate) AS valid_search_flag
            FROM test.test
            )
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE valid_search_flag=1
```

Now on top of this you can run you aggregation query.

I have tested this successfully on SQL Server, Pls make below changes to execute this in mySQL -

(a) FORMAT(searchdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') **-->** GET_FORMAT(searchdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')

(b)  FORMAT(searchdate, 'hh')/3 **-->** HOUR(searchdate)/3